# How do I recover ability to boot into Windows and Old Ubuntu after shrinking windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-repair

I shrunk my windows 10 partition so I could increase my ubuntu 16.04 partition.  I did this from within Windows.

To finish the process I had to reboot, which I did.

(I will note that Windows was downloading and doing a lot of updating throughout this process.  I read in another note that the Windows 10 anniversary update has been reported to delete Ubuntu paritions.)

Eventually I ended up with a grub> prompt.  I rebooted again but was taken right back into the grub prompt.

So, I rebooted with a USB drive.  Tried boot-repair but I understood it to be telling me I couldn't do that from the USB drive. So, I installed Ubuntu to my HDD.

Then when rebooting, I got a boot menu which included Ubuntu (the just installed one) and Window 8 Recovery and Windows 8.  Both of the Windows options said there was missing boot data that prevented booting up.

I would like to be able to boot back into the Windows 10 OS and my original Ubuntu 16.04 installation.  How can I do this?

The report for the boot-repair is located here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26085883

Thank you for any help you may be able to offer.

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: You have an UEFI system, UEFI install of Windows and now a BIOS install of Ubuntu. You can convert Ubuntu to UEFI boot with Boot-Repair's advanced options and total uninstall/reinstall of grub. But you must boot installer in UEFI boot mode. You should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI, but now your Windows entry is missing. You can add a Windows entry with efibootmgr or run Windows repairs from your Windows repair/recovery flash drive. See second entry in IV http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and use extra parameters for sda2.

Comment: @oldfred I am a bit confused about the order of operations here. To convert Ubuntu to EUFI boot, do I need to (1) first boot Ubuntu on USB in UEFI and re-install?  (2) Then uninstall/reinstall grub? (3) Then add a Windows entry with efibootmgr?  (4) What does "use extra parameters for sda2" mean?

Comment: You do not need to totally reinstall Ubuntu. You can just reinstall the correct versions of grub.  And since on gpt disk with ESP - efi system partition, you can just uninstall grub-pc and install grub-efi-amd64. You can use Boot-Repair which makes it a bit easier, but must boot in UEFI mode. See `man efibootmgr` adding new UEFI entry defaults to first drive, first partition. You ESP is second partition so you need `-d /dev/sdX -p Y` where sdX is drive and Y is partition like `sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/sda -p 2`

Comment: Perfect! That worked. I am now able to boot into Windows 10 or into Ubuntu 16.04.  Thank you very much, @oldfred!  Windows is just like it was when I left it. Now, another question:  Before shrinking the Windows partition, I had had another Ubuntu 16.04 partition and installation.  Is there any way to recover that?  When I installed the new Ubuntu 16.04 I am pretty sure that it did not install on top of the old one.

Comment: You only show sda8 as Linux partition, so it does look like you did overwrite. Did you use Something Else install option. That is the best or only way to be sure which partition you install into.

Comment: I don't remember which install option I used.  It was probably best that I started over with a fresh install anyway.

Comment: Just be sure to boot in UEFI mode, so you install in UEFI boot mode. And use Something Else install option and choose existing / (root) as new / partition. IF /home is separate also choose it but be sure NOT to check box to reformat.